# Checking login of external website

Tags: php

Is it possible to check if a user is logged into a external website address? For example, check if the user is logged into a site like amazon.com and if the user is then direct them to a somewhat admin page locally that can only be accessed if the user has logged into that external website.

Basically using the login session of an external service, if it is possible what would be best method to do this in PHP? and is it a safe option?

Apologies is the question is not so clear guys.

Answer (score 2):

Sites like Amazon, Facebook, Twitter, etc. offer OAuth API's that would allow them to log into your site based on their login to the sponsoring site.  You might want to look into this.

Comment: What about site that did not use OAuth?

Comment: @Nicos If they don't use something like OAuth and they are not a site you can work with to come up with your own single sign on implementation, then you would likely be out of luck, as you can't just magically access their login information.

Comment: understandable and thanks. What about using something like the preg_match() function checking the data from the logged in page?

Comment: @Nicos I have no idea what you would be referring to here. I don't get how you would you preg_match on some other server that you have no control over, or what preg_match would do for you even if you could run it on the remote server.

Comment: By using preg_match to look for certain text held only on the logged in account page of the external site. 

if (preg_match("/Logged in as: username/")){ direct to page on local site } else { direct elsewhere }

would it all be possible then? thanks for your help.

Comment: @Nicos Yes, but how would your service have access to that information? If you are not rendering that external website and you don't have the entire contents of this external website passed along to your server with the incoming request, I am not sure how you expect to get this information.